# Microsoft Word: background image for numbered or bulleted lists?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm trying to format some custom bulleted and numbered list styles in Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac.

I'd like to place a background image (or even just a background color) behind each number or bullet in the list. Is this even possible?

Comment: I can't see an obvious way to do that. Here, I have been able to use a picture bullet to achieve something similar, but have never worked out how Word scales pictures in that case, and it never fully simulates using a background colour. Other possibilities: use a 2-column table with a manually inserted bullet character in the first column and a cell background applied, or use a character style to apply foreground/background formatting to a manually inserted bullet. For numbering, similar approach but use manual or field-based numbering.

Comment: Thanks @bibadia! I'm a little shocked that this functionality doesn't exist, but your workarounds sound great. I'll go with one of them. Really appreciate the help!